# Add, rename, remove item in treeview with MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

I refer excellent tutorial of Josh Smith to work with treeview.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

I try to modified with this code to add, remove, rename item to this treeview but I don't know why it not update

Rename item command

```
#region RenameCommand

/// <summary>
/// Returns the command used to execute a search in the family tree.
/// </summary>
public ICommand RenameCommand
{
    get { return _renameCommand; }
}

private class RenameFamilyTreeCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly FamilyTreeViewModel _familyTree;

    public RenameFamilyTreeCommand(FamilyTreeViewModel familyTree)
    {
        _familyTree = familyTree;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        // I intentionally left these empty because
        // this command never raises the event, and
        // not using the WeakEvent pattern here can
        // cause memory leaks.  WeakEvent pattern is
        // not simple to implement, so why bother.
        add { }
        remove { }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Rename command");



        _familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].Children[0].Header = "Hello";

        if (_familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0] == null)
            return;

        // Ensure that this person is in view.
        if (_familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].Parent != null)
            _familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].Parent.IsExpanded = true;

        _familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].IsSelected = true;
    }
}

#endregion // RenameCommand
```

Add item command

```
#region AddCommand

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the command used to execute a search in the family tree.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get { return _addCommand; }
    }

    private class AddFamilyTreeCommand : ICommand
    {
        public FamilyTreeViewModel _familyTree;

        public AddFamilyTreeCommand(FamilyTreeViewModel familyTree)
        {
            _familyTree = familyTree;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        {
            // I intentionally left these empty because
            // this command never raises the event, and
            // not using the WeakEvent pattern here can
            // cause memory leaks.  WeakEvent pattern is
            // not simple to implement, so why bother.
            add { }
            remove { }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Person newPerson = new Person();
            newPerson.Header = "New Person";
            newPerson.Name = "1.1.1.75";
            PersonViewModel newPersonViewModel = new PersonViewModel(newPerson);
            ////_rootPerson.Children.Add(newPersonViewModel);


            //_rootPerson.Children.Add(newPersonViewModel);

            //if (newPersonViewModel.Parent != null)
            //    newPersonViewModel.Parent.IsExpanded = true;

            //newPersonViewModel.IsSelected = true;

            _familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].Children.Add(newPersonViewModel);

            if (_familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0] == null)
                return;

            // Ensure that this person is in view.
            if (_familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].Parent != null)
                _familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].Parent.IsExpanded = true;

            _familyTree._rootPerson.Children[0].IsSelected = true;


        }
    }

#endregion // AddCommand
```

Add command working fine but it's seem to be GUI not update. Rename command is not working but GUI is updated. I don't know reason why, And it's hard to access person class (use parent, person, children,..)

Is there anyone successfully update add, rename, remove command to Josh Smith project.

p/s: I debug by messagebox.show and see binding command for add and rename are working well, But the problem is I don't know what exactly to use Add, remove, rename person in Josh Smith project

Comment: What do you mena by _"Rename command is not working but GUI is updated."_? If the items are renamed then it is obviously working?

Comment: @BionicCode there are 2 controls binding data, treeview and graphic (graphic show node as a flowchart) when i run rename command, graphic update but treeview is not, i don't know why... Beside that, is it a right way to add new, remove, rename item in treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding items is not reflected in the UI, because the source collection `Person.Children` doesn't implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1).
Whenever you need dynamic collections, where add, remove or move operations should update the binding target, you should use the [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Similar applies to the `Person.Name` property. If you want a property's change to be reflected to the UI, then your view model must implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples) and raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event whenever the binding source (the view model property) has changed.

Generally, when a class serves as a binding source for data binding, then this class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (if this interface is not implemented, then the performance of data binding becomes very bad).
When the modification of a property should update the UI (binding.target) by invoking the data binding, then the modified property must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.
When the modification of a collection should update the UI (binding target) by invoking the data binding, then the modified collection must implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and raise the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event. ObservableCollection provides a default implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

The following example follows the above rules. The changes made to the `Person` class should fix your issues. Changes to the data model will now be reflected in the `TreeView`:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _children = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    private string name
    public string Name 
    {
        get => this.name;
        set 
        { 
            this.name = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are save my life, it's work when use INotifyPropertyChanged for person class. I don't realize this thing in MVVM, Really thanks so much and so appreciate about it BionicCode