# How do I remove treeviewitem using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm making a file explorer app using MVVM pattern in C# WPF. Right now I want to implement watcher events that are responsible for adding, removing and renaming items from treeview. I already have adding, and partially renaming (I think that in this case I have to combine deleting and adding). I'm struggling with deletion.

Deleted files are stil in the treeview. For example, Folder shouldn't exist anymore, because I deleted it.

[App window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBuKi.png)

I would very much appreciate help from You. Here's a code I've written in class DirectoryInfoViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ViewModels {
    public class DirectoryInfoViewModel : FileSystemInfoViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<FileSystemInfoViewModel> Items { get; private set; }  = new ObservableCollection<FileSystemInfoViewModel>();

        public bool Open(string path)
        {
            bool result = false;
           
            try
            {
                FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
                Watcher.Created += OnFileCreated;
                Watcher.Renamed += OnFileRenamed;
                Watcher.Deleted += OnFileDeleted;
                //Watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
                Watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
                Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                foreach (var dirName in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
                    DirectoryInfoViewModel itemViewModel = new DirectoryInfoViewModel
                    {
                        Model = dirInfo
                    };
                    itemViewModel.Open(dirName);
                    Items.Add(itemViewModel);
                }


                foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    FileInfoViewModel itemViewModel = new FileInfoViewModel();
                    itemViewModel.Model = fileInfo;
                    Items.Add(itemViewModel);
                }
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception = ex;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public Exception Exception { get; private set; }

  


        private static void Watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) =>
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.GetException().ToString());


        public void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnFileCreated(e));
        }

        private void OnFileCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File Created: " + e.Name);
            if (!Items.Any(x => x.Caption == e.Name))
            {
                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(e.FullPath);
                DirectoryInfoViewModel itemViewModel = new DirectoryInfoViewModel();
                itemViewModel.Model = dirInfo;
                Items.Add(itemViewModel);
            }
        }


        public void OnFileDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnFileDeleted(e));
        }

        

        private void OnFileDeleted(FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            
                Debug.WriteLine("File Deleted: " + e.Name);
            if (Items.Any(x => x.Caption == e.Name))
            {
                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(e.FullPath);
                Debug.WriteLine("File path: " + e.FullPath);
                DirectoryInfoViewModel itemViewModel = new DirectoryInfoViewModel();

                itemViewModel.Model = dirInfo;
                Items.Remove(itemViewModel);
              
            }


        }

        public void OnFileRenamed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnFileRenamed(e));
        }

        private void OnFileRenamed(FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("File Renamed: " + e.Name);

            OnFileDeleted(e);
            OnFileCreated(e);
     
        }
    } }
```

Comment: You do not need to use events in your case, it will be enough to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist) and use it with your observable collection. Also, [do not use events in MVVM at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669964/where-to-put-events-when-using-mvvm). And [do not use messageboxes too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm). Or use MMVM light, for example

Comment: Also, this [question can be helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303305/add-rename-remove-item-in-treeview-with-mvvm-wpf)

Comment: For me events are necessary, because I have to follow my professor's guidelines

Comment: But it's not even MVVM) If something like that was in your professor's guidelines - he don't understand how it works. I'll recomend you to learn it by yourself. Don't mind his notes. For example - here's good article about real [MVVM pattern](https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `private void OnFileDeleted(FileSystemEventArgs e)` you create a new `DirectoryInfoViewModel` and attempt to remove it from the `Items` collection. `ObservableCollection<T>.Remove(T)` removes item based on a reference equality check if `T` does not provide an alternative equality check.

So you attempt to remove an item from for you `Items` collection which is not in the collection. If you check the return value of `Items.Remove(itemViewModel)` you will see that it returns `false` as no item equal to `itemViewModel` was found in the collection (see [Collection.Remove(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.remove?view=net-5.0)).

This would fix the problem by finding the item you want to remove and then removing it.

```
private void OnFileDeleted(FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (Items.Any(x => x.Caption == e.Name))
    {
        var toDelete = Items.Single(x => x.Caption == e.Name);
        Items.Remove(toDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much! You have no idea how much you've helped me! I wish I could upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet (but I will!) However, there's one issue with this solution. When I delete folders containing other sub-folders I get an error saying 'Access denied'. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You should consider using only one `FileSystemWatcher` for your root folder and set `FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories` to `true` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories?view=net-5.0)). I did a quick test and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Could you elaborate? I set FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories  to true and have single FileSystemWatcher (at least I think I do), but it didn't change a thing. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong, because I'm new to this...

Comment: You will have to change most of your code.
Consider this: Before, you had a `FileSystemWatcher` for each directory, so when `OnFileDeleted` was called, you knew that the deleted file/directory was directly contained in the directory your `DirectoryInfoViewModel` represents.
But now, you only have a single Watcher at the root level and you will receive all the events at the root level. This means you cannot compare based on your `Caption` anymore. Instead you have to compare full paths.